# how can i link existing mercurial repo with eclispe IDE

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I am using eclipse as IDE. I had the folder in `/var/www/mysite` which is the repo copied from mercurial server. I pull and push the chnages my going into that folder and type hg pull push etc.

In my eclipse i had defined one empty project and then linked the FOlder to my `/var/www/mysite` so that i can edit the files withe eclipse.

I have now just installed Mercurial Eclipse and now i ahve the option to clone new repo. But is there any way to link the existing mysite folder repo with eclipse because i have ll stuff over there and few files which i am not comming to repo. How can i link that so that ni can do all push pull from eclipse rather than going through terminal

Answer (score 0):

If in your linked project the .hg folder is at the root of the project this should work: In the navigator view, right click on the project and select **Team >> Share..**, then select Mercurial. It will detect the existing Mercurial repository and enable Mercurial capabilities.